# When editing a 'Position' item, I'm unable to add a logo

Tags: bug, developer-story

**Issue:**

I added a *Position* item. When I tried to edit it and add a company logo ("Click to add logo"), the cursor turns to the 'not-allowed'. Clicking does nothing.

**Expected:**

Editing a 'Position' item should allow me to add an image.

Reference image: [image: Developer stories - Edit position, unable to add image/logo]